# Web Apps and Gaming links missing from footer on Super User and Server Fault

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, footer

This has already been raised on [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1537/webapps-link-missing-in-su) but as it affects Server Fault as well I thought I'd raise it here too.

Stack Overflow style footer:

[image: Stack Overflow footer]

Super User/Server fault footer:

[image: Super User footer]

The latter has a link to doctype which is "taking the space" of webapps and gaming on the other footer.

The beta sites have a multiline footer, so lack of space isn't (or at least shouldn't be) an issue.

Comment: I see that, but what link do you want them to take off to put those two on?

Comment: We have one more problem here http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1551/su-meta-communilty-link-missing

Comment: @pramodc84 - the links seem OK now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now fixed on both sites.